# How to get telegram channel message author data on telethon?

Tags: python, telethon

I'm getting 5 latest posts from a channel that publishes not on behalf of the channel, but on behalf of the user. And for each user there is only id. I'm trying to get the rest of his data by id, for example username, but I get an error.
Here is the code of my script:

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.contacts import SearchRequest
from telethon.tl.types import PeerUser, PeerChat, PeerChannel
from telethon.tl.types import InputPeerChat
from telethon import functions

import asyncio
from asyncio import new_event_loop, set_event_loop
import time

from db.users_db import getAllUsersForSend
from db.channels_db import getAllTrChannels

api_id = 'api_id'
api_hash = 'api_hash'

async def bot_auth(client, tg_id):
    # Bot authorization
    if not await client.is_user_authorized():
        await client.start(bot_token='my_bot_token')
    dialogs = await client.get_dialogs()
    for dialog in dialogs:
        if isinstance(dialog.message.peer_id, PeerChannel):
            tr_channels = getAllTrChannels()
            for channel in tr_channels:
                if channel['channel_id'] == dialog.message.peer_id.channel_id:
                    print(dialog.name)
                    print(dialog.message.peer_id.channel_id)
                    messages = client.iter_messages(dialog, limit=5)
                    async for message in messages:
                        print(message.from_id.user_id)
                        from_user = await client.get_entity(message.from_id.user_id)
                        print(from_user)
                        await asyncio.sleep(10)

    # Session termination
    await client.disconnect()

def lets_go():
    users_for_send = getAllUsersForSend()

    for user in users_for_send:
        print(user['tg_id'])

        loop = new_event_loop()
        set_event_loop(loop)

        # Creating a Telegram client
        client = TelegramClient('session_name_testbot', api_id, api_hash)

        # Starting an asynchronous function
        with client:
            client.loop.run_until_complete(bot_auth(client, user['tg_id']))
```

It's displaying an error:

```
Job "lets_go (trigger: interval[0:01:00], next run at: 2024-01-24 14:55:32 +06)" raised an exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:\work\2024\get_vacancy_bot\venv\Lib\site-packages\apscheduler\executors\base.py", line 125, in run_job
retval = job.func(*job.args, **job.kwargs)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "E:\work\2024\get_vacancy_bot\handlers\get_chat_messages.py", line 67, in lets_go
client.loop.run_until_complete(bot_auth(client, user['tg_id']))
File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 653, in run_until_complete
return future.result()
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "E:\work\2024\get_vacancy_bot\handlers\get_chat_messages.py", line 37, in bot_auth
from_user = await client.get_entity(message.from_id.user_id)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "E:\work\2024\get_vacancy_bot\venv\Lib\site-packages\telethon\client\users.py", line 292, in get_entity
  inputs.append(await self.get_input_entity(x))
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "E:\work\2024\get_vacancy_bot\venv\Lib\site-packages\telethon\client\users.py", line 468, in get_input_entity
  raise ValueError(
ValueError: Could not find the input entity for PeerUser(user_id=5919601160) (PeerUser). Please read https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/concepts/entities.html to find out more details.
```

The documentation seems to say that client.get_entity should get data by id. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to get not by id, but by input user.

line 37:
from_user = await client.get_entity(message.from_id.user_id)

replace:

```
from telethon.tl.types import InputUser
from_user = await client.get_entity(InputUser(user_id=message.from_id.user_id, access_hash=message.from_user.access_hash))
```